# Is there any law or axiom for the position and quantity of a natural number?

Tags: arithmetic

I am interested in this question. We all know that for example the natural number **seven** consists of seven **1** *(7=1+1+1+1+1+1+1)* and it is located between **6** and **8**. But is there any law or axiom that would confirm this, or all people just agreed among themselves about it?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I don't know what answer you expect... To use and talk about a particular symbol or word, we must first agree upon the *meaning* of the symbol.  The symbol $7$ and word `seven` are indeed *defined* to be equal to $S(S(S(S(S(S(1))))))$ where $S$ is the successor function, giving the natural number one larger than the input.

Comment: Yes; the definition of *seven* as the successor of *six*, and that of *eight* as the successor of *seven*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like the [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms). @JMoravitz hinted at it in their comment when they referred to the [successor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_function) *S*(*n*).

As far as the choice of assigning the symbol 7 to the value of $S(S(S(S(S(S(1))))))$, that is completely cultural.

Answer (score 4):

It might depend on the formal framework you are using, the arithmetic theory, like some of the most common: PRA, HA or PA.
In all those mentioned axiomatization of arithmetic, you find some kind of construction process formalized, usually a "successor function" satisfying some stuff like "for every well-formed expression n, S(n) is a well-formed expression" and "there is no well-formed expression n, s.t. for the Symbol '0' 0 = S(n) holds.". If you identify now 0 with 0, S(0) with 1, S(S(0)) with 2 and so on, the set $\mathbb{N}$ becomes a model for the theory.
So the location of a number between two other numbers is in the end a result of the construction process (the successor function) and "binding" the natural numbers to it.